# How to fill the Tech Overview data in Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I'm using GA4 Measurement Protocol to record events from a Roku application. This is not a web or Android/iOS app and there's no SDK for GA4, so I need to record events the same way I would do from a server: HTTP requests using the Measurement Protocol as if I had a gtag installed in my app.

If I go to `Reports > Tech > Tech overview` in my property's dashboard I see metrics like:

- Users by Platform
- Users by Operating System
- Users by Device Category
- Users by App version
- Users by Device Model

I don't know how to populate these values using [GA4's Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag). So far my requests look like this

```
POST /mp/collect HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.google-analytics.com
Content-Type: application/json
```

Query params:

```
api_secret: XXXX
measurement_id: XXXX
```

Request body

```
{
    "client_id": "some random id because i don't actually have a gtag to generate it",
    "user_id": "a unique id generated by the device",
    "non_personalized_ads": false,
    "user_properties": {
        "device_id": {
            "value": "same as user_id, just to have it as a user property"
        }
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "custom_event1",
            "params": {

                "engagement_time_msec": "1", // need to have this as > 0 otherwise it GA4 won't show the user
                "session_id": "another random id generated by the device so that i can start a session",
                "param1": "xyz"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For populating the Users by OS table, I read in other posts that I should use the `ua` query param, but it's not working for me with this value, which is what I send to my backend: `Roku/DVP-11.0 (11.0.0.4184-AE)`

Comment: Not sure how you send the request, but maybe you can try the request header's User-Agent ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set below parameters in request headers. [image: sample request header]